# Error multiple definition . I add the keyword 'extern' and again an error

Tags: c++

during compilation I get a 'multiple definition' error and when I add 'extern' keywords in my hpp file, I get other errors.
main.cpp

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "includes/MPU.hpp"
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>


std::ofstream csvFile;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() 
{
    temps = millis();
    i=1;
    wiringPiSetup();
    fd=wiringPiI2CSetup(adresse);

    if (fd==-1)
    {
        std::cout << "Le port I2C n'est pas joignable. Vérifiez les paramètres et connexions."<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Initialisation des capteurs" << std::endl;
        wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,0x6B,0x00);//réveille le capteur en gérant le power_mgmt
        // lireTous();
        initAngles();//récupère les valeurs de repos
               
        std::cout << "Début du programme" << std::endl;
    }
}

void loop() 
{
    getAngles();
    std::cout<<"AngleX="<<angleX-angleX0<<" AngleY="<<angleY-angleY0<<std::endl;
    
    csvFile.open ("example.csv", std::ios_base::app);
    csvFile << angleX-angleX0 << ";" << angleY-angleY0 <<"\n";
    csvFile.close();
      
    delay(1000);
}

int main()
{
    setup();

    for (;;) { 
        loop();
    }
}
```

MPU.hpp

```
#ifndef MPU_HPP
#define MPU_HPP

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>


int adresse=0x68;//adresse du port I2C. 
long int timePrev, temps, timeStep;
double arx, ary, arz, gsx, gsy, gsz, gry, grz, grx, rx, ry, rz;
int fd;
int i=1;
static const double gyroScale = 131; //131 LSB/deg/s
static const double Rad2Degr=57.295779506;//PI=180°
int angleX, angleY, angleZ;
float angleX0, angleY0, angleZ0;


int conversionSigne(double valeur); //le registre contient des données signées (le LSB donne le signe)=>convertion signée
double getAccX();
double getAccY();
double getAccZ();
double getGyroX();
double getGyroY();
double getGyroZ();
void lireTous(); //lecture de tous les registres du capteur MPU6050
float getAngleX();
float getAngleY();
float getAngleZ();
    //cette fonction n'a pas vraiment d'intérêt si le capteur est posé à plat
    //car il est impossible de trouver l'angle de rotation Z
    //étant donné que l'accélération se détermine à partir du vecteur gravitationnel

void getAngles();
    //cette fonction utilise le calcul d'angles par l'accélération
    // puis intègre les données gyroscopiques par filtrage (filtre de Kalman) pour éviter les dérives
    // liées à des chocs ou vibrations occasionnant des accélérations

void initAngles(); //détermine les valeurs lorsque le capteur est au repos (à l'initialisation)

#endif /* MPU_HPP */
```

MPU.cpp

```
#include "includes/MPU.hpp"


int conversionSigne(double valeur) //le registre contient des données signées (le LSB donne le signe)=>convertion signée
{
    if (valeur>=0x8000)
    return -((65535-valeur)+1);
    else
    return valeur;
}

//************************************************************************************

double getAccX()
{
    double temp;
    //lecture des deux octets accélération sur le bus I2C
    temp=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x3B)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x3C);
    return conversionSigne(temp);
}

//***************************************************************************************

double getAccY()
{
    double temp;
    temp=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x3D)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x3E);
    return conversionSigne(temp);
}

//***************************************************************************************

double getAccZ()
{
    double temp;
    temp=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x3F)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x40);
    return conversionSigne(temp);
}

//************************************************************************************

double getGyroX()
{
    return wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x43)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x44);
}

//************************************************************************************

double getGyroY()
{
    return wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x45)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x46);
}

//************************************************************************************

double getGyroZ()
{
    return wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x47)<<8|wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0x48);
}

//************************************************************************************

void lireTous() //lecture de tous les registres du capteur MPU6050
{
    short int temp;

    for (int i=0x0D;i<0x76;i++)
    {
        temp=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,i);
        std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
    }

}

//**************************************************************************************

float getAngleX()
{
    double temp;
    double aX, aY, aZ;

    aX=getAccX()/16384;//16.384 LSB pour 1g d'après la doc
    aY=getAccY()/16384;
    aZ=getAccZ()/16384;

    temp=sqrt( pow(aY,2)

                     + pow(aZ,2));

    return Rad2Degr * atan(aX/temp);
}

//**************************************************************************************

float getAngleY()
{
    double temp;
    double aX, aY, aZ;

    aX=getAccX()/16384;//16.384 LSB pour 1g d'après la doc
    aY=getAccY()/16384;
    aZ=getAccZ()/16384;

    temp=sqrt( pow(aX,2)

                   + pow(aZ,2));

    return Rad2Degr * atan(aY/temp);
}

//**************************************************************************************

float getAngleZ()

{ 
    //cette fonction n'a pas vraiment d'intérêt si le capteur est posé à plat
    //car il est impossible de trouver l'angle de rotation Z
    //étant donné que l'accélération se détermine à partir du vecteur gravitationnel

    double temp;
    double aX, aY, aZ;

    aX=getAccX()/16384;//16.384 LSB pour 1g d'après la doc
    aY=getAccY()/16384;
    aZ=getAccZ()/16384;
    temp=sqrt( pow(aX,2)

                  + pow(aY,2));

    return Rad2Degr*atan(temp/aZ);
}

//**************************************************************************************

void getAngles()
{ 
    //cette fonction utilise le calcul d'angles par l'accélération
    // puis intègre les données gyroscopiques par filtrage (filtre de Kalman) pour éviter les dérives
    // liées à des chocs ou vibrations occasionnant des accélérations

    timePrev = temps;//on mémorise le temps initial pour Dt
    temps = millis();
    timeStep = (temps - timePrev) / 1000; // time-step in s

    //récup des valeurs

    arx=getAngleX();
    ary=getAngleY();
    arz=getAngleZ();
    gsx=getGyroX()/gyroScale;
    gsy=getGyroY()/gyroScale;
    gsz=getGyroZ()/gyroScale;

    if (i==1)
    { 
        //initialement les valeurs gyro=valeurs accel
        grx=arx;
        gry=ary;
        grz=arz;
    }

    else
    {
        grx=grx+(timeStep*gsx);
        gry=gry+(timeStep*gsy);
        grz=grz+(timeStep*gsz);
    }

    delay(50);

    //on filtre
    angleX=(0.04*arx) +(0.96*grx);
    angleY=(0.04*ary) +(0.96*gry);
    angleZ=(0.04*arz) +(0.96*grz);

}

//*********************************************************************************

void initAngles() //détermine les valeurs lorsque le capteur est au repos (à l'initialisation)
{
    std::cout << "Ne pas bouger et laisser le capteur en position d'équilibre"<< std::endl;
    double tx=0;
    double ty=0;
    double tz=0;

    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        getAngles();

        tx +=angleX;
        ty +=angleY;
        tz +=angleZ;
    }

    angleX0=tx/100;
    angleY0=ty/100;
    angleZ0=tz/100;

}
```

Here's the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `adresse'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `timePrev'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `temps'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `timeStep'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `arx'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `ary'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `arz'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x28): multiple definition of `gsx'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x28): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `gsy'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x38): multiple definition of `gsz'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x38): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x40): multiple definition of `gry'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x40): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x48): multiple definition of `grz'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x48): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x50): multiple definition of `grx'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x50): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x58): multiple definition of `rx'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x58): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x60): multiple definition of `ry'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x60): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x68): multiple definition of `rz'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x68): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x70): multiple definition of `fd'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x70): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `i'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x74): multiple definition of `angleX'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x74): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x78): multiple definition of `angleY'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x78): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x7c): multiple definition of `angleZ'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x7c): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x80): multiple definition of `angleX0'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x80): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x84): multiple definition of `angleY0'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x84): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoF0tRj.o:(.bss+0x88): multiple definition of `angleZ0'; /tmp/ccOK7i5e.o:(.bss+0x88): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that this error is because of the includes and the compiler thinks that I declared the same variables several times.

And when I add the keyword 'extern' in my MPU.hpp :

```
extern int adresse=0x68;//adresse du port I2C. 
extern long int timePrev, temps, timeStep;
extern double arx, ary, arz, gsx, gsy, gsz, gry, grz, grx, rx, ry, rz;
extern int fd;
extern int i=1;
static const double gyroScale = 131; //131 LSB/deg/s
static const double Rad2Degr=57.295779506;//PI=180°
extern int angleX, angleY, angleZ;
extern float angleX0, angleY0, angleZ0;
```

Here are the errors that come to me

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:
includes/MPU.hpp:24:12: warning: ‘adresse’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int adresse=0x68;//adresse du port I2C.
            ^~~~~~~
includes/MPU.hpp:28:12: warning: ‘i’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int i=1;
            ^
In file included from MPU.cpp:14:
includes/MPU.hpp:24:12: warning: ‘adresse’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int adresse=0x68;//adresse du port I2C.
            ^~~~~~~
includes/MPU.hpp:28:12: warning: ‘i’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int i=1;
            ^
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `adresse'; /tmp/ccqFn3EU.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `i'; /tmp/ccqFn3EU.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqFn3EU.o: in function `setup()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `temps'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqFn3EU.o: in function `loop()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `angleX'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `angleX0'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `angleY'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `angleY0'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getAccX()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getAccY()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getAccZ()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getGyroX()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getGyroY()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o:MPU.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): more undefined references to `fd' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `getAngles()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x800): undefined reference to `temps'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x804): undefined reference to `timePrev'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x80c): undefined reference to `timeStep'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x810): undefined reference to `arx'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x814): undefined reference to `ary'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x818): undefined reference to `arz'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x81c): undefined reference to `gsx'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `gsy'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x824): undefined reference to `gsz'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x82c): undefined reference to `grx'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x830): undefined reference to `gry'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x834): undefined reference to `grz'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x838): undefined reference to `angleX'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x83c): undefined reference to `angleY'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x840): undefined reference to `angleZ'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDnZfxY.o: in function `initAngles()':
MPU.cpp:(.text+0x974): undefined reference to `angleX'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x978): undefined reference to `angleY'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x97c): undefined reference to `angleZ'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x980): undefined reference to `angleX0'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x984): undefined reference to `angleY0'
/usr/bin/ld: MPU.cpp:(.text+0x988): undefined reference to `angleZ0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the errors _as text_, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you include `MPU.hpp` twice, once from main and once from MPU.cpp. If you define *externally linked symbols* in MPU.hpp, you will get multiple definition errors when linking. The mutable variable `int adresse=0x68` is an example of an external variable.

With each source file including this header file, `adresse` will be defined. To circumvent that, you need to make sure that you only define it `once`. What you need to do, is to put the *definition* in the source file.

`extern` is used for exactly this. But you should only *declare* the variable (not define/initialize it) for each translation unit. If you do `extern int adresse=0x68`, you *still* define the variable in each translation unit.

Correct thing, if you want to have it mutable, to do is set `extern int adresse` in the header, and then in *one* source file, you set `adresse=0x68` (probably `MCU.cpp` in your case).

**But** adresse looks suspicously non-mutable. If you mark it as const: `const int adresse=0x68`, adresse will have *internal linkage*, and can stay in the header.

So mark any constants in the headers as `const` and mark variables shared between multiple source files as `external`. If the variables is only needed in one source file, remove it completely from the header file, and put it into the source file.